# Sorting elements into "bins" C++

Tags: c++, sorting

Hello I've been wondering what was the most efficient way to sort elements into "bins" in c++.

For example, we might have 3 bins:

- Bin A accepts integers from 0-10
- Bin B accepts integers from 5-20
- Bin C accepts integers from 25-30

I want to be able to put an integer into the correct bin based on the range the bin accepts. If the int falls into the range of multiple bins, put it into the bin that is the least full. Finally, I want to be able to tell if the integer doesn't fit into any bin.

**What is the most efficient way to do this?**

Comment: How many bins are there? And what are their sizes? How much is the overlap?

Comment: What have you done so far? What does not work with that? All in all, what you describe seems to be a straight forward task.

Comment: Juts to be clear: how about a value of (say) 7 - does this go into *both* Bin A *and* Bin B?

Comment: @Thomas Ah! - I missed that bit (oops).

Comment: Can you have the case where all the bins are the same?

Comment: Can a bin contain multiple instances of the same number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

If the number of bins is small, a simple linear search is usually plenty efficient. Especially if you take into consideration the programmer's time.

If the set of integers is small and the bins don't often overlap, it can be done in constant time. We create a vector indexed by the integer, with as value another vector of (pointers to) the bins. So you can look up the list of applicable bins in constant time. You still need to loop through the applicable bins to find out which is the least full, so this is only constant time if the maximum number of overlapping bins is bounded by a constant.

If the set of integers is large but the bins themselves are relatively small, we can do something similar, but using a hash table instead of a vector.

If we can't make any assumptions, then an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is probably the best solution. But its worst-case behaviour is still linear in the number of bins, because the bins might all overlap and would all need to be checked to find the one that is least full.